# converting to timestamp with time zone failed on Athena

Tags: sql, date, hive, amazon-athena, timestamp-with-timezone

I'm trying to create to following view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_events AS 
(
   SELECT
     "rank"() OVER (PARTITION BY "tb1"."innerid" ORDER BY "tb1"."date" ASC) "r"
   , "tb2"."opcode"
   , "tb1"."innerid"
   , "tb1"."date"
   , From_iso8601_timestamp(tb1.date) as "real_date"
   , "tb2"."eventtype"
   , "tb1"."fuelused"
   , "tb1"."mileage"
   , "tb1"."latitude"
   , "tb1"."longitude"
   FROM
     rt_message_header tb1
   , rt_messages tb2
   WHERE ((("tb1"."uuid" = "tb2"."header_uuid") AND ("tb2"."opcode" = '39')) AND ("tb2"."type" = 'event'))
   ORDER BY "tb1"."innerid" ASC, "tb1"."date" ASC
)
```

and it gives me the following error:

> Your query has the following error(s):
>   Unsupported Hive type: timestamp with time zone

however when I run the query on it's own it works fine, and the From_iso8601_timestamp is mentioned [here](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html) as a valid date function.

can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

## Short summary:

```sql
SELECT CAST(From_iso8601_timestamp('2018-01-01T15:00:00Z') AS timestamp) as "real_date"
```

## Full story:

Unfortunately Athena doesn't fully support all Presto features, it has [limitations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/other-notable-limitations.html) and is technically a few versions behind Presto. There's some attempt to make Athena integrate closely with the AWS Glue Metastore, which while based on Hive's metastore has some inconsistencies. I wish that Spark, Hive, Glue, Athena, Presto et al would just work with the same metastore, it would make life easier, but back to your issue:

This [document about an older teradata fork of Presto](https://teradata.github.io/presto/docs/141t/release/unsupported.html) mentions some issues with timestamp in presto:

> Presto’s method for declaring timestamps with/with out timezone is not
> sql standard. In Presto, both are declared using the word TIMESTAMP,
> e.g. TIMESTAMP '2003-12-10 10:32:02.1212' or TIMESTAMP '2003-12-10
> 10:32:02.1212 UTC'. The timestamp is determined to be with or without
> timezone depending on whether you include a time zone at the end of
> the timestamp. In other systems, timestamps are explicitly declared as
> TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE or TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE

The version of Presto that Athena is forked from does support both `timestamp` and `timestamp with timezone` but with that quirk as mentioned in the teradata docs which shouldn't be an issue. The real issue is that [Athena does not support timestamp with timezone](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/data-types.html).

The presto docs you've linked to show that the function returns a value of that unsupported type `timestamp with timezone`, so you need to cast it as something else that is supported. It's an oversight that Athena allows functions and casting to a datatype that is then not supported, and hopefully that will be remedied, but for now you have to work around it.

What you need to do is use the `CAST()` function around that function call, which will change the type from `timestamp with time zone` into `timestamp`

Unfortunately you probably can't cast the string directly to a timestamp, although it depends on how the string is formatted. You also can't use the style of casting where you write `timestamp` before the string e.g. can't do `timestamp '2018-01-01 15:00:00'` for reasons I will explain below.

### Type returned by the `from_iso1601_timestamp()` function

```sql
SELECT typeof("real_date") AS real_date_type
FROM
(
SELECT From_iso8601_timestamp('2018-01-01T15:00:00Z') as "real_date"
)
```

> timestamp with time zone

### This doesn't work

```sql
SELECT typeof("real_date") AS real_date_type
FROM
(
SELECT CAST('2018-01-01T15:00:00Z' AS timestamp) as "real_date"
)
```

> SQL Error [FAILED]: INVALID_CAST_ARGUMENT: Value cannot be cast to
> timestamp

### This style of Casting also returns timestamp with timezone :(

Note that the SELECT part of this works, and it says that it is a `timestamp`, but for some internal inconsistency reason you can't create a view and you'll get an error.

```sql
CREATE OR replace VIEW test 
AS 
SELECT typeof( "real_date" ) AS real_date_type
FROM
(
SELECT  timestamp '2018-01-01 15:00:00' as "real_date"
)
```

> SQL Error [FAILED]: Could not initialize class
> com.facebook.presto.util.DateTimeZoneIndex

For whatever reason, creating a view requires that java class while parsing the value in the select doesn't. It's a bug that should be addressed.

### This works yay

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW test
AS
SELECT typeof("real_date") AS real_date_type
FROM
(
SELECT CAST(From_iso8601_timestamp('2018-01-01T15:00:00Z') AS timestamp) as "real_date"
)
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use the following syntax in Athena over Timestamp data type (dt):

```
SELECT id,dt,dt AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' as dateTimeNY FROM Table
```

Answer (score 5):

Ran into something similar on something that I was working on recently. AWS Support pointed me to Davos solution but it didn't end up working for my case. The solution that ended up working from me was:

```
create or replace view db_name.vw_name AS
select
    from_unixtime(cast(to_unixtime(current_timestamp) AS bigint)) as field_name
from db_name.tbl_name
```

This will convert the output of `current_timestamp` which is `timestamp with time zone` to `timestamp`

If you want to verify the data type of the field, you can use:

```
select typeof(field_name) from db_name.vw_name
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for this addition, it seems like a useful alternative.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
cast(replace(cast(at_timezone(<YOUR_DATE_FIELD> , 'US/Eastern') as varchar) ,'America/New_York', '') as timestamp),
typeof(cast(replace(cast(at_timezone(<YOUR_DATE_FIELD> , 'US/Eastern') as varchar) ,'America/New_York', '') as timestamp))
from 
<YOUR_TABLE>
```

Lets say <YOUR_DATE_FIELD> is in UTC . The first at_timezone function will change the date to EST format ,but will have the extra literal 'US/Eastern' appended to it.

The next step is to cast it as varchar so as to remove the literal. However , when casting to varchar , it changes to 'America/New_York' which is what needs to be replaced with ''. Finally cast it to timestamp

Comment: Please explain your answer.  Why does it work ?

Answer (score 0):

Casting like *Koustav* answer in my case is the only solution to get the real time paris_without_tz and it works with both athena `select` and `ctas`

```
CREATE TABLE test WITH (format = 'PARQUET', write_compression = 'SNAPPY') AS 
select timestamp '2022-11-30 23:00:00.000' as utc
, at_timezone(timestamp '2022-11-30 23:00:00.000', 'Europe/Paris') as tz_paris
, CAST(at_timezone(timestamp '2022-11-30 23:00:00.000', 'Europe/Paris') as timestamp) AS remains_utc
, CAST(replace(CAST(at_timezone(timestamp '2022-11-30 23:00:00.000', 'Europe/Paris') as varchar), ' Europe/Paris', '') as timestamp) AS paris_without_tz
```