# Convert DateString with offset to a valid Date/Timestamp in Athena / Presto

Tags: sql, datetime, amazon-athena, presto, timezone-offset

I am trying to convert a date string field to a date. Problem is the string field has offset for Eastern time in it. How to convert it to date time?

Date String: `2016-09-21T10:01:43-04:00`

This has to be converted to valid Date Time in Amazon AWS Athena.
Tried From_iso8601_timestamp, date_parse. But no luck.

Comment: [converting to timestamp with time zone failed on Athena](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50832977/1699210)

Comment: Tried it, but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`from_iso8601_timestamp`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#from_iso8601_timestamp):

```
presto> select from_iso8601_timestamp('2016-09-21T10:01:43-04:00');
             _col0
--------------------------------
 2016-09-21 10:01:43.000 -04:00
```

(tested on Presto 309, but should work in Athena too)