# AthenaQueryError: Athena query failed: "NOT_SUPPORTED: Unsupported Hive type

Tags: hive, presto, timestamp-with-timezone, amazon-athena

I recently ran into the following error "AthenaQueryError: Athena query failed: "NOT_SUPPORTED: Unsupported Hive type", and for this I followed this stack overflow link: [converting to timestamp with time zone failed on Athena](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50832977/converting-to-timestamp-with-time-zone-failed-on-athena)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzFcO.png):

The weird part of the whole issue is the sql query that is generated as I use an internal python plugin is working fine as I run it manually in Athena but the same doesn't work in a jupyter notebook

Comment: It'd be great to know what causes this error, to me the same thing has happened. Keep us posted here if you find out something about this.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the same as yours, But I ran into the same error when I was extracting some JSON data using `json_extract`, it works fine with Athena, but fails inside a Jupyter Notebook, throwing the same error as yours.

Putting `json_format` before `json_extract` solved it for me.
casting json into an array also solved it.

Here is a example SQL code using `json_format`:

```
SELECT col1,col2 
json_format(json_extract(col3, '$JSPath')) AS some_alias 
FROM some_database
```

Here is the other one using `CAST`

```
SELECT col1,col2 
CAST ((json_extract(col3, '$JSPath')) AS ARRAY(JSON)) AS some_alias 
FROM some_database
```

Comment: I'm using the AWS Wrangler package and had the same problem. Using `json_format` to convert the output to string fixed my issue. Thanks for this solution  

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was that I was doing a `CROSS JOIN` on json, so far so good, but forgot to **NOT** select it in the `SELECT` statement.

This was my query:

```sql
SELECT
    *,
    JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(experiments, '$.feature_flag_name') AS experiment_name,
    JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(experiments, '$.feature_flag_variant') AS experiment_variant
FROM
    actions AS a
CROSS JOIN
    UNNEST(CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(payload, '$.feature_flags') AS ARRAY(JSON))) AS t(experiments)
```

As you can see, I was casting alright, but due to `SELECT *` I ended up selecting from the joined table as well, which contained JSON and which in turn produced the error in question.

Restricting the SELECT statement to `SELECT a.* ...` of course solved the issue.